# how to add new line series runtime in nvd3 line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 charts.
I want to add a new line series in already loaded line chart. 
Or is there a way to create ROI (Draw a dynamic region) on chart?